# Ubuntu installing id3 php

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, id3

I'm having issues installing php-id3 I'm using the following and getting this response:

```
sudo pecl install --force id3
WARNING: failed to download pecl.php.net/id3 within preferred state "stable", will instead download version 0.2, stability "alpha"
downloading id3-0.2.tgz ...
Starting to download id3-0.2.tgz (20,693 bytes)
........done: 20,693 bytes
4 source files, building
running: phpize
Cannot find config.m4.
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

If the command failed with 'phpize: not found' then you need to install php5-dev packageYou can do it by running 'apt-get install php5-dev' as a root userERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Ahhh easy fix I hear you scream you need the php dev packages!! Well I alread have them:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5-dev is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 246 not to upgrade.
```

so what am I missing to get this module installed?

Comment: the config.m4 file, which should've been provided by whoever packaged  the id3 .tgz.

Comment: @MarcB thank you for your answer, how do I get this file? i've not built this from source I've simple used the version from the apt-get repo

Comment: no idea. contact the package maintainer?